# Rails 4: using offset on a randomized list produces unexpected results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, generator, offset

...or maybe, i just don't get it.

TL;DR - i get totally randomized results with duplicates and such. No idea why.

Here's the problem - i'm trying to make a rails app generating tournament brackets. The user can select whether he'd like to randomize the team list when generating the bracket, or later assign the teams by himself.

If i choose the latter option and generate the bracket as the ids go, everything is fine. 
If i choose to randomize the list, the list itself is fine, but later when assigning teams to particular matches (in a loop), the resulst are completely unorganized and unexpected (at least to me) eg.

instead of
Match 1: Team 1 vs Team 2
Match 2: Team 3 vs Team 4
etc. (as in the normally generated list)

i get something completely random with frequent duplicates like:
Match 1: Team 1 vs Team 1
Match 2: Team 1 vs Team 9

```
if @seed = 'random'
  @team_list = @tournament.teams.order("RAND()")
else
  @team_list = @tournament.teams.order(:id)
end
```

Here's how i assign the teams. The thing that screws everything up seems to be the "offset" part, and i don't get it, why.

```
@match.team_a = @team_list.offset((2*match_number)-2).limit(1).first               
@match.team_b = @team_list.offset((2*match_number)-1).limit(1).first
```

EDIT:

A sample of @team_list data as requested. That's the randomized one.

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation 
[#<Team id: 2, team_name: "test_team_a", reputation: 0, created_at: "2016-08-25 09:29:20", updated_at: "2016-08-26 11:08:21", team_leader_id: 2>, 
#<Team id: 9, team_name: "test_team_b", reputation: 0, created_at: "2016-08-30 23:01:17", updated_at: "2016-08-30 23:01:17", team_leader_id: 2>, 
#<Team id: 3, team_name: "test_team_c", reputation: 0, created_at: "2016-08-30 22:59:16", updated_at: "2016-08-30 22:59:16", team_leader_id: 2>, 
#<Team id: 7, team_name: "test_team_d", reputation: 0, created_at: "2016-08-30 23:00:35", updated_at: "2016-08-30 23:00:35", team_leader_id: 2>, 
#<Team id: 5, team_name: "test_team_e", reputation: 0, created_at: "2016-08-30 23:00:07", updated_at: "2016-08-30 23:00:07", team_leader_id: 2>, 
#<Team id: 6, team_name: "test_team_f", reputation: 0, created_at: "2016-08-30 23:00:23", updated_at: "2016-08-30 23:00:23", team_leader_id: 2>, 
#<Team id: 4, team_name: "test_team_g", reputation: 0, created_at: "2016-08-30 22:59:41", updated_at: "2016-08-30 22:59:41", team_leader_id: 2>, 
#<Team id: 8, team_name: "test_team_h", reputation: 0, created_at: "2016-08-30 23:00:46", updated_at: "2016-08-30 23:00:46", team_leader_id: 2>]>
```

Comment: Could you possibly add a sample of data in your @team_list?

Comment: added right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to shed some more light on the above answer, when you do `@team_list = @tournaments.teams.order("RAND()")`, that does this query (presumably in SQL):

```
SELECT teams.* FROM teams ORDER BY RAND()
```

(I know teams belongs to tournaments, but you get my point.)

And then when you do `@team_list.offset(x).limit(1)`, that does this query:

```
SELECT teams.* FROM teams ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 OFFSET x
```

Because of ActiveRecord relations, each time you do a new thing, you're doing a query. You can test this out in rails console - it'll tell you the queries it does.

EDIT:

If you want to use your code as is, just convert the result of the first query to an array and don't use offset/limit. So:

```
@team_list = @tournaments.teams.order("RAND()").to_a
...
@match.team_a = @team_list[2 * match_number - 2]
@match.team_b = @team_list[2 * match_number - 1]
```

This means that you will be loading all of the teams at once (I think) and not lazily loading them as ActiveRecord relations allow you to do.

Comment: You're probably right, and i'm just asking because i still seem to not understand the way it works. 

I tried it in console and everytime i tried @team_list, i'd get the same result, but when offset is used the results are random. I don't get it why in the first case aren't the results also randomized.

Comment: Er honestly, I'm not an expert on how ActiveRecord relations work, so I'm not sure any explanation I give will be technically accurate. But my guess is that when you assign `@team_list` to the result of the query, the relation saves the order into the variable, but it still carries the equivalent query behind it. I'm going to update my answer to include an alternative.

Comment: yep, your answer works just right. thank you for that

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using offset.  Each time you change the match_number you end up doing a new query (which includes the call to order_by rand()).  You need to make @team_list the result of your database query and then to organize the matches in some other way so you are not hitting the database repeatedly.  This will also dramatically improve performance.

Try something like

```
@team_list.each_slice(2) do |team_a, team_b|
end
```

Comment: I think i would still need to offset it, because this way it only assigns the first two teams to each match from my understanding. That's why I used offset in the first place. Maybe you have an idea how to solve it otherwise? 

Also maybe i'm still understanding it incorrectly, but when i try it in the console everytime i try @team_list, the result seems to be the same (and not randomized each time it's querried), but then when offset is used, the results are randomized.

Comment: See [`each_slice` docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice). If your teams are [1, 2, 3, 4], then `each_slice(2)` will give you [1, 2] on your first iteration and [3, 4] on your next.

Comment: @user3758208 this is only to replace your loop part, you still want the if seed part above it otherwise it won't be randomized.  The issue you are running into is that each time you're assigning a team using the offset it is getting the nth team from a list with a completely different order as the one before it.